# Requirements for deploying a ASP.NET MVC web application to a hosting company

Tags: asp.net, deployment, hosting

I have tried creating an ASP.NET MVC application which works perfectly when "locally" deployed, I want to deploy to an online web hosting company. I am beset by errors like trust level not right (tried to set it in web.config but the hosting company doesn't allow changing that, so how to specify it?) - tried creating a basic "empty" web site with no database access, file system access etc but just a static html page and I get "don't know what ASP.NET web pages version to use"

What do I need to look for in a suitable web host to be able to create a simple web application and deploy it to my domain - Seems like it should be a simple task but I am totally frustrated by silly issues.

The easy part is actually writing the code - the hard part seems to be deploying and running the wretched thing!!!

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment

Comment: Does your web host have a support section or knowledge base? If so, cut-n-paste the error message into their search box or into google and also add `site:support.mywebhost.com` (or whatever their support url is).